# Machine learning algorithm for this task?

Tags: machine-learning

Trying to write some code that deals with this task:

- As an starting point, I have around 20 "profiles" (imagine a landscape profile), i.e. one-dimensional arrays of around 1000 real values.
- Each profile has a real-valued desired outcome, the "effective height".
- The effective height is some sort of average but height, width and position of peaks play a particular role.
- My aim is to generalize from the input data so as to calculate the effective height for further profiles.

Is there a machine learning algorithm or principle that could help?

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that there's some unknown function `f` that takes a length-1000 array (a "profile"), and produces a scalar output (a "height"), and you're looking for an algorithm that can learn to approximate `f`?  I know little about machine learning, but my intuition tells me that 20 training items are probably insufficient (unless you can **heavily** constrain the type of function that `f` can be).

Comment: Yes, this is the scenario. I could probably downsample the input arrays from length-1000 to 200 but that is still too much? Does that mean I should first extract a handful of characteristic values (how many?) that I suspect to play a role, and then throw them into a machine-learning algorithm to figure out how to combine them?

Comment: I think you are still going to need to constrain `f`.  Just think how many possible functions there are that could give you your 20 outputs.

Answer (score 2):

**Principle 1: Extract the most import features, instead of feeding it everything**

As you said, "*The effective height is some sort of average but height, width and position of peaks play a particular role.*" So that you have a **strong priori assumption** that these measures are the most important for learning. If I were you, I would calculate these measures at first, and use them as the input for learning, instead of the raw data.

**Principle 2: While choosing a learning algorithm, the first thing to care about would be the the linear separability**

Suppose *the height* is a function of those measures, then you have to think about that **to what extent the function is linear**. For example if the function is almost linear, then a very simple Perceptron would be perfect. Otherwise if it's far from linear, you might want to pick up a multiple-layer neural network. If it's far far far from linear....please turn to principle 1, and check out if you are extracting the right features.

**Principle 3: More data help**

As you said, you have *around 20 "profiles"* for training. In general speaking, that's not enough. Almost all of the machine learning algorithms were designed for somehow big data. Even they claimed that their algorithm is good at learning small sample, but usually not as small as 20. **Get more data!**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe multivariate linear regression suffices?

Comment: It might if `f` is known to be a linear combination of the inputs.

Comment: But it certainly won't help if there are only 20 test cases.

Comment: No, it is not a linear combination at all. From what I have seen, the peaks seem to play the most important role, and the "valleys" should be ignored. I have played around with things like squares, or the harmonious mean of (nominal_height - x), or ignoring some of the smallest values. All this brought me pretty close but it is not good enough, so I thought machine learning could help.

Comment: I would resort to some generic approach like neuronal networks, then. However, I would really try to get some more domain knowledge to get a better informed heuristic/solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a combination of what you said about which features play the most important role, and then train a regression on that. Basically, you need at least one coefficient corresponding to each feature, and you need substantially more data points than coefficients. So, I would pick something like the heights and width of the two biggest peaks. You've now reduced every profile to just 4 numbers. Now do this trick: divide the data into 5 groups of 4. Pick the first 4 groups. Reduce all those profiles to 4 numbers, and then use the desired outcomes to come up with a regression. Once you have trained the regression, try your technique on the last 4 points and see how well it works. Repeat this procedure 5 times, each time leaving out a different set of data. This is called cross-validation, and it's very handy.

Obviously getting more data would help.